# Flutter Showduration on Tooltip with triggerMode.tap not work

Tags: flutter, dart, tooltip

if I set the triggerMode to tap, the tooltip remains open until you tap somewhere else. The ShowDuration is ignored. To remedy this, I put a GestureDetector around it (which I don't think is such a nice solution). Does anyone know maybe a better solution to the problem.

```
class CustomTooltip extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTooltip({
    Key? key,
    required this.tooltip,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.only(left: kSpacingS),
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String tooltip;
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  @override
  State<CustomTooltip> createState() => _CustomTooltipState();
}

class _CustomTooltipState extends State<CustomTooltip> {
  GlobalKey _toolTipKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        final dynamic _toolTip = _toolTipKey.currentState;
        _toolTip.ensureTooltipVisible();
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
        _toolTip.deactivate();
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: widget.padding,
        child: Tooltip(
          key: _toolTipKey,
          // triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kSpacingM),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(kSpacingL),
          showDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
          message: widget.tooltip,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: CColor.blueDark.withOpacity(0.9),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(kSpacingXS)),
          ),
          textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          // TODO ui
          child: const Icon(Icons.info_outline),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```